# Salto de línea para varios autores en RMarkdown

Tags: markdown, r-markdown

Deseo elaborar un documento PDF en RMarkdown con varios autores, entonces para la portada:

```
---
title: "Ejercicio 2 pregunta 2"
author: 
- "Perfidio "  
- "Franegan"
- "Efren"
- "PJkalamity13"
date: "27/09/2020"
output: pdf_document
---
```

Sin embargo, de esta manera coloca a todos los autores en la misma línea.

**¿Cómo puedo colocar a cada autor en cada línea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la [pagina](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1716#issuecomment-560601691) de problemas del repositorio del paquete `rmarkdown` **cderv** da esta solución

```
---
title: "Ejercicio 2 pregunta 2"
author: 
- "Perfidio "  
- "Franegan"
- "Efren"
- "PJkalamity13"
date: "27/09/2020"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \renewcommand{\and}{\\}
---
```

El autor menciona que esto le puede ayudar siempre y cuando no use el comando `\and` en otro sitio del documento.